# Why not just check this instanceof fBound in the bind method polyfill?

Tags: bind, polyfills

This is an older version of `bind` method polyfill from MDN:

```js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") {
            // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
            // internal IsCallable function
            throw new TypeError( "Function.prototype.bind - what " +
                "is trying to be bound is not callable"
            );
        }

        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP = function(){},
            fBound = function(){
                return fToBind.apply(
                    (
                        this instanceof fNOP &&
                        oThis ? this : oThis
                    ),
                    aArgs.concat( Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ) )
                );
            }
        ;

        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

        return fBound;
    };
}
```

And I'm confused with `this instanceof fNOP` here. I know sometimes we may call the fBound return by `bind` method as a constructor function. Like this:

```js
const fn2 = fn1.bind()
new fn2()
```

So I think the purpose of `this instanceof fNOP` is to help judge how we call the function return by `bind` method and do something relatively. But why no just check `this instanceof fBound` here? If the fBound is called as a constructor function, then `this` must be an instance of fBound, right?

**PS:** The latest version of bind polyfill has turned the `this instanceof fNOP` check into the `fNOP.prototype.isPrototypeOf(this)` check, but I think the purpose is the same. Anyway, it still check `fNOP` instead of `fBound`, which I can't quite understand.